# XamlParseException when adding a usercontrol into a project

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I created a user control in a project that consists of just a MainWindow.xaml and the code behind. I added the .dll to the toolbox of VS, and dropped it onto a window in a new project. This created the following:

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication5"
        xmlns:ThinkGeoClean="clr-namespace:ThinkGeoClean;assembly=ThinkGeoClean" x:Class="WpfApplication5.MainWindow"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" >
    <Grid>
        <ThinkGeoClean:ListBoxCustom x:Name="listBoxCustom" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The `ThinkGeoClean` is the name of the .dll I added which is the usercontrol. `ListBoxCustom` is just a public class in the control, but is NOT what I want to show. I want to show the main window of the usercontrol (not a window), but it doesn't show as an option after typing `<ThinkGeoClean:`. The only thing that shows up is `ListBoxCustom`. If I go ahead and type `<ThinkGeoClean.MainWindow>`, it gives a XamlParseException error on that line.

Now, if I go into the code-behind and do:

```
ThinkGeoClean.MainWindow newWin = new ThinkGeoClean.MainWindow();
newWin.Show();
```

It will pop up the usercontrol in a new window and it works fine.

Here's the beginning of usercontrol code behind:

```
namespace ThinkGeoClean
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
```

And the xaml for it is just a single grid containing some buttons and a map control.

Edit: In addition to the answer below, my user control was originally just a normal WPF project. I thought changing the output type to a class library would change it into a user control automatically, but I actually had to go into the xaml and change the the  into .

Comment: Xaml can't show windows, if it could you could popup a message box from xaml. This is due to the visual tree not accepting Window as a child. It can only be a parent.

Comment: have u add the reference correctly ?! does it copy to your build location ?!

Comment: Shoot. Alright I'm going to try changing the control into an actual <UserControl/> instead of <Window/>. I thought I could just change the project output to "Class Library" and it would work, guess not though. Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to make `ThinkGeoClean.MainWindow` the root element in your Xaml (e.g., replacing `Window`), or are you trying to make it a descendant of the `Window`?  The former should be legal, but the latter is not.

Comment: I was trying to make it the descendant. Thank you. I have to go back to the control and change the window into usercontrol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <ThinkGeoClean:ListBoxCustom x:Name="listBoxCustom" />
</Grid>
```

...is *not* equivalent to creating an instance of a window and call the `Show()` method on it programmatically.

Instead the XAML processor will try to add the window to the `Children` collection of the `Grid` and this is not possible since a window cannot be child of another control. That's why you get an exception.

Also, a `UserControl` must be hosted in a window or page. It is not a top-level control that you can display without any parent host.